# Uniq method active record ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When use **.uniq** (Active Record Query Method), he any way are ordening my result in array. i need remove ordering when use uniq.

I need to keep order using **.uniq** method, how can do solve this?

without **.uniq**:

```
[#<Coupon:0x0000001cadced0
  id: 838882461,
  name: "HOW_TO_CODE_50",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 50,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001cadc408
  id: 922059944,
  name: "HOW_TO_CODE_70",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 70,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001cae3bb8
  id: 469697148,
  name: "LEARN_RUBY_20",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 20,
  quantity: 10,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001cae3190
  id: 68100775,
  name: "HOW_TO_CODE_NOT_USED",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 1000,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: false,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001cae2998
  id: 214172726,
  name: "LEARN_RUBY_30",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 30,
  quantity: 10,
  available_until: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>
  ]
```

with **.uniq**:

```
[#<Coupon:0x0000001c786498
  id: 68100775,
  name: "HOW_TO_CODE_NOT_USED",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 1000,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: false,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001c7859d0
  id: 214172726,
  name: "LEARN_RUBY_30",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 30,
  quantity: 10,
  available_until: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001c784fa8
  id: 387313615,
  name: "GLOBAL_DEMO",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 75,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001c784800
  id: 469697148,
  name: "LEARN_RUBY_20",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 20,
  quantity: 10,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Coupon:0x0000001c784008
  id: 548707893,
  name: "HOW_TO_CODE_FREE",
  token_type: "manual",
  value: 100,
  quantity: 5,
  available_until: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 18:01:24 UTC +00:00,
  percentual: true,
  school_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 18:01:25 UTC +00:00>,
 ]
```

Comment: I am little unclear about your question. You mean that you don't want the elements in array reorder on aplying uniq ? Can you please make it clearer?

Comment: yep, i need keep order of uniq, without use uniq.

Comment: whats your question..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order` along with `uniq`:

```
# assuming you want to sort by name

Coupon.where(...).uniq.order(name: :desc)
```

Use `:asc` instead of `:desc` to reverse order. See [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) docs for more.